# How to get sticky broadcast data when BroadcastReceiver is enabled?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a `BroadcastReceiver` that is registered on the manifest and it is initially disabled `android:enabled="false"`.

Manifest:

```
<receiver
            android:name="com.sample.name.MainWidgetBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.sample.name.intent.action.METADATA_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

The intent I receive `com.sample.name.intent.action.METADATA_UPDATE` is sticky.  How can I get this sticky data when I enable the receiver? It would be fine if the solution triggers the BroadcastReceiver or if I have to pull it my self.  I would prefer not having to register the broadcast just to get this data...

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                new ComponentName(context, MainWidgetBroadcastReceiver.class),
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Comment: I posted code on how to enable the Broadcast at the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oops! I guess I should read the APIs harder... [registerReceiver(null, intentFilter)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#registerReceiver%28android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.content.IntentFilter%29) would do it!

> If you know the Intent your are registering for is sticky, you can
>   supply null for your receiver. In this case, no receiver is registered
>   -- the function simply returns the sticky Intent that matches filter. In the case of multiple matches, the same rules as described above
>   apply.